# piping ls to other programs vs loop globbing

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, wildcards

I am reading about [the pitfalls of parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and the examples given are about looping ls with for/while. The article title says 'parsing ls' - does that mean piping the output of ls to awk and other programs is just as bad?

```
ls /my/path/ | awk '{print $NF}'
```

When piping output of ls to other programs, is it better to loop a glob instead?

```
for p in /my/path/*; do
    echo "$p" | awk '{print $NF}'
done
```

I assume since ls can potentially output newlines etc piping ls directly to other programs is also 'a bad practice' but I don't see much information in that respect.

Comment: It does and so does the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

While looping a glob is safer than piping the output of `ls`, keep in mind that the output of `ls` is only as dangerous as you make it. If you are the sole user of the system, and you are sensible about naming your files, then piping `ls` is not a big deal. As your article mentions, it is really only when you start putting odd characters (newlines, pipes, etc) into your file names that these issues arise. I would really only be concerned about safely piping ls when using a system that is shared among a large group of people or has files randomly generated by some program. For just general use on a private computer, sensible file naming is probably simpler than writing a loop.

Comment: It’s as dangerous as *the programs you run* make it. Do you know absolutely everything that every single program you run does?